# Run Command Prompt then auto enter input

Tags: python, windows, cmd

when I run this on my command prompt:

```
"C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\bin\\openvpn.exe" --config "C:\\Users\\users\\project\\sample\\ovpns\\au599.nordvpn.com.udp1194.ovpn"
```

it asks for two inputs:

```
Enter Auth Username:
Enter Auth Password:
```

now when i run it using python:

```
cmd = '"C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\bin\\openvpn.exe" --config "C:\\Users\\users\\project\\sample\\ovpns\\au599.nordvpn.com.udp1194.ovpn"'
p=Popen(cmd,stdin=PIPE)
```

It also asks for two inputs. I want python to automatically enter the inputs.

So I tried this:

```
cmd = '"C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\bin\\openvpn.exe" --config "C:\\Users\\users\\project\\sample\\ovpns\\au599.nordvpn.com.udp1194.ovpn"'
p=Popen(cmd,stdin=PIPE)
p.stdin.write("username\n")
p.stdin.write("password\n")
```

But it did not work.

Comment: You shouldn't be putting plain text passwords in scripts anyway.

Comment: Just to clarify something… your initial command line example is incorrect, it is using double backward slashes, when those should be single. ```"%ProgramFiles%\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn.exe" --config "%UserProfile%\project\sample\ovpns\au599.nordvpn.com.udp1194.ovpn"```